# Struggling to figure out this VBA array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have been trawling SO posts and Mr.excel and other links google gives me, but I just cannot figure this out.

I am trying to build an array of `string` values that exists in my excel document and then `loop` through them to display all the values it finds.

I have the following code which all seems to work besides for me trying to build this array and then display items in the array. Could someone please assist me or send me in the right direction.

```
Sub openExcel()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
Dim mynewstring As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim txt As String





Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With xlApp
.Visible = False
.EnableEvents = True
End With

strFile = "C:\Users\michaelm\Documents\Clients\emails.xlsx"

i = 0
Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
Set sourceWH = sourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
sourceWB.Activate
mynewstring = sourceWH.Cells(2, 1).Value
LastRow = sourceWH.range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

MyArray = sourceWH.range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value


 For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
    MsgBox (MyArray(i))
  Next i


ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
xlApp.Quit



MsgBox (mynewstring)


End Sub
```

The error I seem to be getting most of the time is `"Subscript out of range"`

I am so lost :) Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: When debugging, what is the value of `UBound(myArray)`?

Comment: @Gareth - The value is 4.

Comment: change `For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray)` to `For i = LBound(MyArray) to Ubound(MyArray)` and change `MsgBox (MyArray(i))` to `MsgBox MyArray(i, 1)` and retry

Comment: @vba4all, Tried that one already as well :) Same error. I'm wondering if my array even has anything in it? this is why I am trying to `msgbox` myself the values.. but it is proving to be quite difficult for me. haha

Comment: @Mike u sure? I've edited the above comment and included the code to access `MyArray` elements

Comment: @vba4all - That worked!! haha.. What was I doing wrong if I may ask? Thanks ... Mike :)

Comment: `MyArray` is a 2D array. When accessing it you need to specify both dimensions.

Comment: Wow - Thanks so much man! If you make that an answer, Ill mark as correct for you. Thank you very much.

Comment: obviously `for i=1 to Lastrow` , does the trick , why using other numbers when you already know the array size. Also `msgbox Myarray(i,1)`, to get the data. More to say, your lastrow formula will be wrong if ANY blank cell.

Comment: i don't see the part where you declare the variables. Anyway, Myarray must be a Variant (not string as you are saying). Also, i don't understand why you write `i=0', wich should be 0 when using `dim i as Long`, then not use i, and then use a `for` loop, wich will set the value(s) of `i`.

Comment: `sourceWB.Activate` is not needed in the way you use your code, just replace `activeworkbook.close` with `sourceWB.close`. Also in the given code, you open SourceWB, activate it, do NOTHING with it (not read, not write) and then close it with saving changes. makes no sense at all